# Configuration for EJB lookups at runtime

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I have several services deployed as EJBs on a JBoss-AS-7.1 server. Many applications use these EJBs by doing a lookup like this:

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/FooService/FooBean!com.xyz.FooBeanRemote")
private FooBeanRemote fooBeanRemote;
```

The problem is that the lookup string is hard-coded in the source. I want to be able to change this lookup at runtime - without a re-compilation - because FooService may be updated some time in the future, and perhaps have a different implementation. In addition, the ejb could also move to a different server instance.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use ejb-jar.xml instead of annotation ([check here](http://tomee.apache.org/ejb-refs.html))
2. use InitialContext in your code to lookup for bean and move bean name to properties file
3. Implement CDI producer methods in separate jar

--EDIT---
Quick HOWTO about last point:

**1. Create qualifier**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface FooService {
}
```

**2. Create producer method**

```
public class EJBProducer {
    @Produces
    @FooService
    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/FooService/FooBean!com.xyz.FooBeanRemote")
    private FooBeanRemote fooBeanRemote;
}
```

**3. Use in your code**

```
@Inject @FooService
private FooBeanRemote fooBeanRemote;
```

Two first points may be in another jar archive (remember to include there META-INF/beans.xml file). You can also use producer method instead of field, and access ejb  programmatically.